# Build error at Xamarin for IOS - Java.Interop could not be find

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I've tried to build my App in Visual Studio / Xamarin. Android is working fine. I get the error for IOS, that the Java.Interop assembly could not be find. I read that it could be the Mono.Android Assembly. But when I remove it from my c# main project the Android project can't be build. Any suggestions what I can try to do that both systems can be build correctly?

I'm using Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 with newest Xamarin.

Cannot find the assembly 'Java.Interop, Version=0.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065' referenced from '/Users/[user]/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/[myApp].iOS/6f60bd3b7d1dca37df26b69d9b9f708b/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/Mono.Android.dll'.

Could not link assemblies. Reason: Error while processing references of '[myApp].iOS, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have a reference to Mono.Android within your Forms / iOS project, that's why when trying to build, will try to reference java.interop. Check your solution, if there is not reference to Android in iOS project or PCL / Forms.